# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS failed with a kernel panic

Tags: grub2, kernel, boot-repair, lts, 16.04

I tried to upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 using `update-manager -d`.

After installing new packages/updates, my system is not booting.
it's showing the following error.

```
drm_kms_helper : panic occurred, switching back to text console.
```

Comment: Just to help clarify:  Did 16.04 ever boot on your system?  Had you tried using 16.04 from a live USB to see if it would work with your hardware?

Comment: Selected different options in advance setting (grub advanced setting)
and system booted with 16.04 using that.

but system not booting with default ubuntu option (1st grub option).

Comment: IIRC this is a known bug that's mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: Yes it bug, officially reported too.

Comment: finally, I installed latest kernel manually and now system working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues, now the machine started to work if I select the "systemd" boot option.